# RuntimeSchema in Protostuff cyclic references?

Tags: java, protostuff

We're using Protostuff's RuntimeSchema to serialize our data.
This mostly works but we sometimes get:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at io.protostuff.runtime.ObjectSchema.mergeFrom(ObjectSchema.java:350) ~[protostuff-runtime-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
at io.protostuff.CodedInput.mergeObjectEncodedAsGroup(CodedInput.java:336) ~[protostuff-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
at io.protostuff.CodedInput.mergeObject(CodedInput.java:298) ~[protostuff-core-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
at io.protostuff.runtime.RuntimeUnsafeFieldFactory$15$1.mergeFrom(RuntimeUnsafeFieldFactory.java:1217) ~[protostuff-runtime-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
```

This obviously means we've some sort of cyclic reference inside our objects.
Reading the documentation Protostuff theoretically do support cyclic references in runtime schemas, is there a configuration I need to enable for this to work?

I read about: `Dprotostuff.runtime.collection_schema_on_repeated_fields` but it's suppose to apply only to cyclic reference of array items which is not the case in our objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Protostuff supports multiple encoding formats (`protobuf`, `json` and its own `graph`).

If your objects contain cyclic references, then only one is suitable - `graph`. You can use it with `io.protostuff.GraphIOUtil`.

Please note that other encodings (`json`, `protobuf`) cannot support cyclic references (it requires additional information to be included into serialized form, which is not really possible there).

Some additional information on this topic can be found here: http://www.protostuff.io/documentation/object-graphs/